# Duplicate a row record in same table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I want to duplicate a row record in same table but with modifications on some column values. I know i can duplicate a row record by using the following script.

```
INSERT INTO table_name( 
column_name1, column_name2, column_name3 ....
)
SELECT column_name1, column_name2, column_name3 ....
FROM table_name WHERE id=1;
```

But it will duplicate the whole row. For modification i further need to add update script.

So my question is, is there any simpler way to handle my scenario. 
Since the table in which i am working have around 40 columns, so i think this way is not feasible.

Any new ideas are most welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which columns do you want to alter and which values do you want to use?

Comment: For e.g Remarks column in which i want to set "Duplication of record No ..."

Comment: You didnt provide enough information. `I want create a duplicate but different` is very vague Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @Juan Whenever you duplicate a row in same table, at least the primary key/column should be different. So i meant to say that in duplicating a row in same table, how can we update that primary key.

Comment: First you create a column `SERIAL` this is autonumeric and create the next sequence for you. Then in your `INSERT` you dont include it. Neither the field name or the value and db handle for you

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Change values of columns directly in SELECT, the aditional update is   needless, just like in the below example

```
INSERT INTO table_name( 
column_name1, column_name2, column_name3 ....
)
SELECT column_name1, 
       'New string value of column 2', 
       column_name3,
       ......
       ......
       1234 as new_val_of_col_25,
       column_name26,
       ......
FROM table_name WHERE id=1;
```